# How to change the color of the icons in the navigation bar in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have modified the color of the navigation bar to put a lighter color:

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor" tools:targetApi="1">@color/navigation_bar</item>
```

Now the problem is that the icons on the bar are still blank so they are hardly visible. How can you change the color of these icons?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: My recommendation in Jetpack Compose is that you should draw behind the system bars & use insets to manually draw the status & navigation bar so that you can control the color based on mutating states.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your navigation bar is light, you can use this function to make the icon on navigation bar easy to see

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, window.decorView).isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = true
        setContent {
             ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With this modification I continue to see the buttons the same as in the photo that I put in the question. They don't change color

Comment: I just tested again on my device (Pixel 4XL). If I set `isAppearanceLightNavigationBars = true` the color of icon on navigation bar is dark grey.  If I set it to false the color of icon on navigation bar is white.

Comment: My device is a Pixel 3 and nothing changes changing that property, it always looks the same

Comment: can you try to add `<item name="android:windowLightNavigationBar">true</item>` to your theme

Comment: With your first response and in other device it's work. Thanks!